# Mac OSX: users vs dscl command to list user

Tags: macos

I executed those two commands in terminal:

```
users
```

and

```
dscl . -read /Users/
```

and then they tell me two different results. The second one gave me a long list while the first one just showed my username on Mac.

When I google for "List users on Mac", most will tell me use the second one. However when I execute "man users", it shows me that this command is to "list current Users".

Could you tell me the differences?

Also, how do I execute a command as mysql user. The following command didn't work:

```
mkdir mysqldir --user mysql
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you got your username on your Mac for `dscl . -read /Users/` because I get `name: dsRecTypeStandard:Users` which is what I would expect since it's trying to read a `dsRecType` (which is `Users` in this case, mind).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dscl . -read /Users/` doesn't print anything particularly interesting; you probably mean `dscl . -ls /Users`, which prints a list of user accounts that are defined on your computer (including a great many normally-hidden system accounts). `users`, on the other hand, prints a list of users *who are currently logged in* on your computer (usually just you).

For your second question: you can use the `sudo` command to run commands as another user (e.g. `sudo -u _mysql mkdir mysqldir`). Note that this requires admin rights, and will ask you to enter your password for verification.

Answer (score 30):

#### Get a list of all users (just their short names):

```
dscl . -list /Users
```

#### Get detailed user info on a particular user:

```
dscl . -read /Users/<username>
```

#### Get a particular value in a user's info:

```
dscl . -read /Users/<username> <key>
```

Examples of `<key>` are `RecordName`, `RealName`, `UniqueID`, and `NFSHomeDirectory`.

#### Get detailed user info on *all* users:

```
dscl . -readall /Users
```

#### Get a particular value in *all* users' info:

```
dscl . -readall /Users <key>
```

Hopefully you notice the difference between `-list` and `-read`. Additional goodies: `-plist` outputs as XML, `-search` lets you specify a key and value and you will get output indicating where that value is.

```
2rs2ts:~/ $ dscl . -search /Users RealName "Andrew Garrett"          [12:04:07]
2rs2ts      RealName = (
    "Andrew Garrett"
)

2rs2ts:~/ $ dscl -plist . -read /Users/nobody                        [12:05:29]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:AppleMetaNodeLocation</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Local/Default</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:GeneratedUID</key>
    <array>
        <string>FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAAFFFFFFFE</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:NFSHomeDirectory</key>
    <array>
        <string>/var/empty</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:Password</key>
    <array>
        <string>*</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:PrimaryGroupID</key>
    <array>
        <string>-2</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName</key>
    <array>
        <string>Unprivileged User</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName</key>
    <array>
        <string>nobody</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordType</key>
    <array>
        <string>dsRecTypeStandard:Users</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:SMBRID</key>
    <array>
        <string>501</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID</key>
    <array>
        <string>-2</string>
    </array>
    <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:UserShell</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/false</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Of course, you can read the man pages to get more info.

Answer (score 2):

The 'users' command only lists the currently logged-in users.

DESCRIPTION
     users lists the login names of the users currently on the system, in
     sorted order, space separated, on a single line.