# How to get all the user name in Mac OS

Tags: mac

I install the LAMP in my mac. Some folder need the write access. I plan to change the owner to the apache owner, but I don't know the id/group of the apache owner.
How can I get all the user names in Mac OS?

Comment: Might want to check out [this other question](http://superuser.com/questions/592921/mac-osx-users-vs-dscl-command-to-list-user)

Comment: @MrStatic Thx. The link is what I need. I use `dscl . -ls /Users` to list all the users, and `dscl . -read /Users/_www` to get the user detail. And the `dscl . ls /Groups` can get the group info.